# Get column headers with query language

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using the [query language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) to query data from spreadsheet.
I would like to retrieve the first row(column headers), how do I do that?

Currently I'm using: `select * where ( A = -1 )`
, the data in A column is never equal to -1, so it returns only column headers.

Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `query(A:Z, "select * limit 0", 1)` meaning: select all, return at most 0 rows. The result is that only the header row is returned (the 3rd parameter is to make it clear there is 1 header row).

But it's not really natural to use `query` for this purpose. The function `array_constrain` is provided for the purpose of truncating an array of data. For example,

```
=array_constrain(A:Z, 1, 1e7)
```

returns the first row of the given array. (Since no limit on the number of columns is needed, I gave 1e7 = 10,000,000 as the maximal number of columns. A spreadsheet can't even have that many cells.)